# Dynamically set TextArea width

Tags: javascript, css

In Javascript TextArea How to set its width dynamically,

I tried with below code which works only for the last Id am passing as Argument.

Please help me to find what am doing Wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
textarea {
    border : 1 black;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    background-color: yellow;
    resize: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var observe;
if (window.attachEvent) {
    observe = function (element, event, handler) {
        element.attachEvent('on'+event, handler);
    };
}
else {
    observe = function (element, event, handler) {
        element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    };
}
function loadTArea (ids) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        var text = document.getElementById(ids[i]);
        function resize () {
            text.style.height = 'auto';
            text.style.height = text.scrollHeight+'px';
        }

        /* 0-timeout to get the already changed text */
        function delayedResize () {
            window.setTimeout(resize, 0);
        }

        observe(text, 'change',  resize);
        observe(text, 'cut',     delayedResize);
        observe(text, 'paste',   delayedResize);
        observe(text, 'drop',    delayedResize);
        observe(text, 'keydown', delayedResize);
        text.focus();
        text.select();
        resize();
    }    
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loadTArea (['text1','text2']);">
<textarea rows="1" style="height:1em;" id="text1"> sadfa daf </textarea>
<textarea rows="1" style="height:1em;" id="text2"> sadfa daf </textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your question is too localized, give us some context so that we can give you a general solution that other people can benefit from. SO is about questions and answers knowledge base, and your question in its current state hardly qualifies for a knowledge base.

Comment: THANKS FOR ALL YOUR SUPPORT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/8kqJH/

**code**

```
function loadTArea(ids) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        var text = document.getElementById(ids[i]);

        function resize(el) {                       //changes here
            el.style.height = 'auto';
            el.style.height = text.scrollHeight + 'px';
        }

        function delayedResize() {
            window.setTimeout(resize, 0);
        }
        observe(text, 'change', resize);
        observe(text, 'cut', delayedResize);
        observe(text, 'paste', delayedResize);
        observe(text, 'drop', delayedResize);
        observe(text, 'keydown', delayedResize);
        text.focus();
        text.select();
        resize(text);                  //changes here
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

To change textarea dinamycally while user types:

function resize:

```
function resizeTextarea(){
    this.style.height = 'auto';
    this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

event binding:

```
document.getElementById("text1").onkeyup = resizeTextarea;
document.getElementById("text2").onkeyup = resizeTextarea;
```

OR, to apply to all textareas without specifying the ID

```
var text = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
for(var x = 0; x < text.length; x++)
    text[x].onkeyup = resizeTextarea;
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/LbMzD/3/

Comment: In Jfiddle Ur link also has the same problem.Thanks for reply.

Comment: try to add some random text to the textareas, write more than one line of text. then press the button.. it will update the textarea height. the resize funcion now works. isn't this what you were looking for?

Comment: but ur sample asks me to refresh everytime by clicking LoadTexatArea button.

Comment: do you need the textarea to be automatically resized while user is typing ?

Comment: Thank you but here for same functionality we have duplicate code how to bring that into single method and call for multiple textareas with its ids.Thats what I want.Please help me to achieve this.Thanks .

Comment: I've edited the answer, have a look if that satisfies your needs

Comment: I know this is old, but is setting the width/height to `"auto"` before the actual number necessary? The OP was doing it, but I don't think it does anything, unless it's for a different browser or something.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the element you want to resize to your function:

```
var element = document.getElementById(ids[i]);

function resize(element) {
    element.style.height = value;
}

resize(element);
```